# Python tempfile module's temporary directory issues

Tags: python, temporary-files, python-3.5

So I have created the following function which takes an image the user chooses from the tkinter file browser, opens it, re-saves it as a `.gif` (which is **required**) in a **temporary directory**, and then sets it as the background of the tkinter canvas:

```
def background():
   # Create temporary directory and return path as 'tmp'
   tmp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
   # Ask user for image file
   cng = filedialog.askopenfilename()
   # Open the image using the PIL's `open` function
   img = Image.open(cng)
   # Supposed to save image to the `tmp` directory as a GIF
   img.save(tmp + cng + '.gif', 'GIF')
   # Supposed to set image file from temporary directory as background picture
   bgpic(tmp + cng + '.gif')
```

However, whenever the above code is run, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'var/folders/g_/099nlyhn51gf_sy21gvcp2fc0000gn/T/tmpj2z501ml/Users/Name/Pictures/ImageName.jpg.gif'
```

Apparently the directory cannot be found even though I created it with `temple.mkdtemp()`.**What am I doing wrong here that is causing this error?** Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to append the entire path to the file onto the temprary directory (so instead of `/path/to/tmpdir/ImageName.jpg.gif`, you're using `/path/to/tmpdir/Users/Name/Pictures/ImageName.jpg.gif`.

You didn't specify on which line the error is happening, but I suspect you're getting an error when trying to *save* the file, because those intervening directories don't exist.

Consider just taking the basename of the file:

```
img.save(os.path.join(tmp, os.path.basename(cng) + '.gif'), 'GIF')
```